# Why having mvn plugin of maven-resources-plugin version 2.6 complains about maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources failed?

Tags: java, maven

I have `maven version 3.0.5` and `eclipse oxygen`. I included following `plugin`into my mvn project,

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
</plugin>
```

it works fine however when I changed the version to `2.6` in the `pom.xml`. It threw an error saying...

```
Execution default-testResources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources failed: 
A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6
:testResources: org/apache/maven/shared/filtering/MavenFilterException
....
```

I don't understand why that particular version is not accepted and I would like to understand why.

Comment: This error indicates that a class is missing during build time.  I would suggest as a first step deleting `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven` directory and rebuilding.  Perhaps maven or eclipse failed to get the correct dependencies when you changed version level.

Comment: @KyleAure: Understood. Will give a try. Ty for your advice.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it.

Comment: @KyleAure: I will keep looking for a solution. In the meantime, version 2.4 is acceptable. Have a good one!

Comment: Are you updating version for a specific behavior?  If so I would also suggest just updating to the latest version (3.1.0) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-resources-plugin